# How to make a specific environment disappear?

Tags: environments, latex-base

I have got several Tikz pictures whose compilation takes up much time. More generally, I am wondering whether there is a switch that can make a specific environment `foo` disappear as if the code would not exist, similar in effect to the `comment` environment.

Basically, given

```
\begin{foo}
Whatever happens here
\end{foo}
```

I want a switch that makes this environment completely ineffective as if it weren't in the Latex code.

Comment: You can always redefine environments, like with `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{+b}{\iffalse#1\fi}{}`. But maybe you could provide a use case that better shows what you're after? Do you want to keep the place, for example?

Comment: If the pictures don't change often, you could also use tikzes [external](https://tikz.dev/library-external) library

Comment: ... Unless the `external` library doesn't work for the particular pictures in question. (Some it works fine for; some not.) You could also put the pictures' code in separate files and load it with a macro you can then easily redefine. E.g. `\newcommand* \mypicloader[1]{\input{#1}` and `\renewcommand* \mypicloader[1]{}` which lets you exempt some `tikzpicture`s if you want to.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672685/is-there-an-easy-way-to-hide-an-environment-with-an-if-statement/672688

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine and introduce a switch if you already have plenty of code instances of the same environment. So, expanding on Jasper Habicht's comment, you could do the following:

- create a switch
- redefine the environment in question
- in the redefined environment, enclose a regular environment within an if clause (based on the switch), so it depends on that switch.

LaTeX already has a built-in mechanic to create custom *if*'s. Have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression).

Since you have mentioned `tikz` in your question, I made an example upon `tikzpicture`. Here is how to put everything together. Every time you use `\tikzpicsfalse` you are going to turn off `tikz`, whereas `\tikzpicstrue` is going to bring it back.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\iftikzpics
\tikzpicsfalse   % \tikzpicstrue to turn pictures on

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldtikzpicture}{tikzpicture}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{O{}+b}{%
  \iftikzpics
    \begin{oldtikzpicture}[#1]
      #2
    \end{oldtikzpicture}\fi}{}


\begin{document}
X
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=2,
    baseline,
    every node/.style = {draw},
  ]
  \node [transform shape] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```